# Making an HTTP GET request from ejabberd mod_register

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I have setup an ejabberd server. When a user registers I need to make a GET request to another server to notify of the user registration.
The URL is:

```
http://localhost:2555/registration?reg=true&id=xyz
```

How do I make a GET request from within the mod_register module in the ejabberd config file?
The mod_register is as follows:

```
 {mod_register, [
          {welcome_message, {"Welcome!", 
                     "Welcome to this Jabber server."}},
          {access, register}
              //GET Request
         ]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are looking for a solution involving some programming in Erlang.

1. You can patch ejabberd's mod_register directly at the point where registration is successful. See for example `send_registration_notifications/2`. This is quick and dirty, but would not work accross ejabberd upgrades.
2. You can configure ejabberd's mod_register to send registration notifications with option  `registration_watchers` to a bot, and design such an xmpp bot so that it will access your URL whenever it receives these notifications. You could use [exmpp](http://processone.github.io/exmpp/) as a starting point. They provide a tutorial to write a bot.

To access your URL from Erlang, the easiest would be to use built-in HTTP client, and in particular [`httpc:request/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/httpc.html#request-1).

Comment: I created an external module and hooked it up with the existing one. It allows me to perform my own logic in a chain of events while performing a registration and in offline messages. Would this be a problem in future upgrades of ejabberd?

Comment: It simply depends on how much you rely on non-stable APIs.